# Can I deploy Strapi to a sub-folder of existing website(by using Apache reverse proxy)?

Tags: node.js, apache, strapi

For example, I have a website is https://example.com/, and I would like to access the Strapi site by URL https://example.com/strapi/, my Apache reverse proxy configuration is:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass        /strapi http://0.0.0.0:1337/
ProxyPassReverse /strapi http://0.0.0.0:1337/
```

Anyone know the solution? I know to use sub-domain instead the sub-folder maybe a solution, but that's not the way I want to go.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm trying it with nginx, but no luck so far.

Comment: I also asked at https://strapi.slack.com/, someone answered me but I didn't make it works, I spent few days on this issue, but no luck for me. I'm using Apache as HTTP server. I suggest you post your question to Slack and wait. Good luck.

Comment: I wasted quite some time on this as well, and couldn't get it to work properly.